# Trello API access works for only one person

Tags: javascript, authorization, trello

I'm making a very simple application linked to the Trello API that is supposed to perform Elo ranking among the cards in a certain list. The app is here:

http://ranker.teleport.ninja/

I'm using the simple authorization script provided by Trello:

```
Trello.authorize({
  type: "popup",
  name: "Elo ranker",
  scope: {
    read: true,
    write: true },
  expiration: "never",
  authenticationSuccess,
  authenticationFailure
});
```

Now, the application works for myself, but when anyone else tries to use it they get the following error message:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (OK)

Even though they are users who have access to the relevant board. Neither authenticationSuccess nor authenticationFailure are ever called. I'm assuming this has something to do with the key that I passed pas parameter to Trello's client.js, but have no idea where to go from here.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

I never use the trello Api but have you follow the steps here: https://developers.trello.com/get-started#connect

Comment: Yes I have, the code I posted is basically what is presented in the page you mention...